# Vb6 and access Date range

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

Used these queries with MySql Successfully but they arent working with SQL/VB.. any help appriciated

Present Month Records..Starting from 1st day of the current month till now.

```
SELECT * FROM `dt_table` WHERE  date between  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND CURDATE()
```

Present Year Records..Starting from 1st Jan of the current Year till now.

```
SELECT * FROM `dt_table` WHERE  date between  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() ,'%Y-01-01') AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```sql
Select * 
From dt_table 
Where Fix([date]) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1) And Date()
```

and

```sql
Select * 
From dt_table 
Where Fix([date]) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 1) And Date()
```

or

```sql
Select * 
From dt_table 
Where [date] >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 1) And [date] < DateAdd("d", 1, Date())
```

Comment: both are not including current date also Im Trying for current date query but failed... Select * From dt_table Where [date] like Date()

Comment: If so, you have a time part included in field [date]. You can remove that. See edited answer, please (alternative showed for the last only).